# Oracle Varrays foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I created a varray of integers in oracle.

Then I created a table with one of the columns that has this varray.  But when I try to add a foreign key to this column, I wasn't able to do it.

So is it possible to have a varray which is a foreign key?  If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be argued that Varrays violate the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefor the 1st normal form.

It is probably better to properly normalize the data model and sidestep the problem altogether...